# Automatically making steam booster packs

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I wanted to automate the process of making booster packs on steam. I don't know where to start from. I know java and basics of javascript,C.

I can login to my account with steamkit2. I tried searching steam web api and using IInventoryservice, it shows access denied and I don't know if the ExchangeItem method can be used for crafting booster packs. I don't know if I am on right path. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself.
make request - https://steamcommunity.com//tradingcards/ajaxcreatebooster
with parameters - (session id , appid , series = 1 , tradability_preference = 2)